# Distance tracking underwater

Tags: sensor, distance, water, tracking

For a design project at school I need a way to track a short distance underwater (swimming pool).
I have looked into programming an accelerometer to measure the distance traveled, but that is not accurate enough for the purpose I would like to use it for. IR and GPS are both not suitable to use for underwater purposes either because of accuracy and interference issues. I was thinking about ultrasonic waves but this seems to be an expensive solution. Any suggestion is welcome!

**edit:**
The aim of the project is help visually impaired/blind swimmers. I need to track the distance between them, while swimming, and the end of the swimming pool in order to advice them when to turn because this is a big trouble for them. So, How can I measure the distance between two points in the water, one moving and one stationary, in order to sent a signal when a certain distance is achieved?

Comment: Look up something called "sonar".

Comment: So what level of accuracy do you need?

Comment: Pretty high! I need to track a distance very close to the edge of the swimmingpool so the tolerance of the measurement should be around 10/20cm. Moreover I have the problem of lightness so the sensor (or whatever) should be very tiny.

Answer (score 1):

### Tactile

Blow a horizontal jet of warm water from the wall at the end of the swim lane.  (Cold water might work too.  The jet should have a different temperature, compared to the rest of the pool, so the swimmer can feel it.)

### Audio

Place a low power underwater speaker at the end of each swim lane.  The perceived sound volume will give swimmer a cue about how far he is from the end of the lane.

These methods aren't mutually-exclusive, obviously.

*p.s.*  Either way, let's call this thing Zanus-Alexeev device.

Comment: This is EE.SE. I'd feel remiss if I didn't point out the option of attaching arrays of electrodes to the edge and sensing disturbances in the (electric) force.